# Rails: CanCan, models

Tags: cancan

I installed devise, cancan and rolify.

Users who are logged in, created Citys.

I want cancan to show only the Citys from each User.

Therefor:

**I dont understand the relationship between User and City?** There is no foreign key.

I found this:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

can :read, City, :active => true, :user_id => user.id

Comment: "I want cancan to show only the Citys[sic] from each User." As in you only want a user to be able to view they created? How do you track which cities were created by which user in the DB? If you don't track it, that's the first thing you'll need to add.

Comment: ok. On sign up, i want assign automatically a role. I cant find the devise action sign up. Where to add the code user.add_role("Role")?

Comment: i tried this:    <div>
      <%= f.hidden_field(:role, "role")  %>
    </div> i get undefined method `merge' for "role":String

Comment: <%= f.hidden_field(:role, :value => "sportler")  %> then i get after submit Can't mass-assign protected attributes: role

Comment: attr_accessor ! Its done